# Populate bulk data from google spreadsheet into google form dropdown list

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google form with multiple sections, each section with a dropdown list. I wish to pull the data for the dropdown lists from spreadsheet with matching name.

This is the script i run but it doesn't seems to be working.

```js
function getDataFromGoogleSheets() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
const [header, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
const choices = {}
header.forEach(function(title, index) {
  choices[title] = data.map(row => row[index]).filter(e => e !== "");
});
return choices;
}

function populateGoogleForms() {
  const GOOGLE_FORM_ID = "1nsDQ6MtdCci-g5XgLxJ-4XNJ19E9sDz42G6DoFLwiFE";
  const googleForm = FormApp.openById(GOOGLE_FORM_ID);
  const items = googleForm.getItems();
  const choices = getDataFromGoogleSheets();
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    const itemTitle = item.getTitle();
    if (itemTitle in choices) {
      const itemType = item.getType();
      switch (itemType) {
        case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
          item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
          item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
          item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
          break;
        default:
        Logger.log("Ignore question", itemTitle);
       }
    }
  });
}
```

This is a copy of the data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jfzuVF64QoMIauyFy5Plxv0nQwukf8sMnFXIAyzyK0s/edit#gid=0

And here is a copy of the google form:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1nsDQ6MtdCci-g5XgLxJ-4XNJ19E9sDz42G6DoFLwiFE/edit

Please help!

Comment: Can't access form. Could you make it public?

Comment: I tried you code on my form and it works great.  In fact, I really enjoyed learning  about this line `const [header, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();` Thanks.  What would that sort of declaration be called in a reference.  Yes I'm still an ES6 noob.

Comment: @NikkoJ. I am sorry my oversight. Just made the form public.

Comment: I went into your spreadsheet and it run just fine for me and it seem to load all of the questions that matched the header names.  If your looking to load the rest of the questions you will have to add more data columns with the appropriate headers

Comment: @MiMi i can see those options in the form now. But when i add in more options and run the script again they dont populate my new options. I am wondering if it because of some security or setting?

Comment: @MiMi oh i have gotten it to work!! Thanks.. But i have another qn.. My actual data in last column has 102 rows, so now the other questions have a lot of empty options. How can i remove the empty options?

Comment: Done done! All resolved!

Answer (score 1):

I already had multiple choice form and so I just renamed the headings and generated some data (see table below).  I played around with your code because I'd never seen a declaration like in the fourth line.  Pretty cool thanks.  I tried you code on my form which I created manually and to my surprise it worked the first time.

```
function getDataFromGoogleSheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const [hA, ...rows] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const cols = {};//just made some minor changes to fit my personal likes in labeling
  const col={};
  const idx={};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => { cols[h] = rows.map(r => r[i]);col[h]=i+1;idx[h]=i; });
  return cols;
}

function populateGoogleForms() {
  const GOOGLE_FORM_ID = getGlobal('formid');//Have the id stored in a spreaddsheet.  Other than that though it's exactly the same code
  const googleForm = FormApp.openById(GOOGLE_FORM_ID);
  const items = googleForm.getItems();
  const choices = getDataFromGoogleSheets();
  items.forEach(function (item) {
    const itemTitle = item.getTitle();
    if (itemTitle in choices) {
      const itemType = item.getType();
      switch (itemType) {
        case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
          item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
          item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
          item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
          break;
        default:
          Logger.log("Ignore question", itemTitle);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Data Sheet:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Image of the Populated form:

[image]

I was surprised to find that it will take as many choices as you provide.  Thanks for the code.

> Your last question involves this line and I was thinking about this last night before I went to sleep and I finally realized what that additional filter was for.  It's for the columns that don't have as many choices as the one with the most.  I originally did not understand that so I removed it when I constructed this line:

`hA.forEach((h, i) => { cols[h] = rows.map(r => r[i]);col[h]=i+1;idx[h]=i; });`

but should have done it this way:

`hA.forEach((h, i) => { cols[h] = rows.map(r => r[i]).filter(e=>e!=''); });col[h]=i+1;idx[h]=i; });`

And that filter removes all of the blanks at the end of the shorter columns.

So just to be clear here's the final solution:

The code:

```
function getDataFromGoogleSheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const [hA, ...rows] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const cols = {};
  const col={};
  const idx={};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => { cols[h] = rows.map(r => r[i]).filter(e=>e);col[h]=i+1;idx[h]=i; });
  return cols;
}

function populateGoogleForms() {
  const GOOGLE_FORM_ID = getGlobal('formid');
  const googleForm = FormApp.openById(GOOGLE_FORM_ID);
  const items = googleForm.getItems();
  const choices = getDataFromGoogleSheets();
  items.forEach(function (item) {
    const itemTitle = item.getTitle();
    if (itemTitle in choices) {
      const itemType = item.getType();
      switch (itemType) {
        case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
          item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
          item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
          item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
          break;
        default:
          Logger.log("Ignore question", itemTitle);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And here's the data that I used this time:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 9 | 17 |
| 18 | 19 | 13 |
| 14 | 14 | 14 |
| 3 | 13 |  |
| 4 | 7 |  |
|  | 6 |  |
|  | 1 |  |
|  | 8 |  |

And here's the form:

[image]

Comment: @Copper i cant get it to work in my google form. i m wondering if it is because of the multiple sections i have.

Comment: i keep seeing this error message Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier line: 1 file: Code.gs

Comment: I used my global functions to pick up my id and they aren't available to others.  I don't think that you need to change your code.

Comment: i have made my form and spreadsheet public. could you help me to see what went wrong? it just doesn't populate the data into the form with the script..... sigh.

Comment: I apologize but I don't follow links to spreadsheets

Comment: ohhhhh.. Sad :(

Comment: i have gotten it to work!! Thanks.. But i have another qn.. My actual data in last column has 102 rows, so now the other questions have a lot of empty options. How can i remove the empty options?

Comment: That's funny that you should ask about that because just before I went to sleep last night I was thinking about what the reason was for the filter at the end of the command in your original code.  And of course in my example I used columns that were equal in  length so I didn't see the problem.  I added another section to my answer so hopefully that will help.